# Key Error while preprocessing of data (onehot encoding)

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

I am getting a key error while converting the variables using onehot encoder. This is the code that i used:

```
def preprocessor(df):
    res_df = df.copy()
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

    res_df['"job"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"job"'])
    res_df['"marital"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"marital"'])
    res_df['"education"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"education"'])
    res_df['"default"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"default"'])
    res_df['"housing"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"housing"'])
    res_df['"month"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"month"'])
    res_df['"loan"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"loan"'])
    res_df['"contact"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"contact"'])
    res_df['"day_of_week"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"day"'])
    res_df['"poutcome"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"poutcome"'])
    res_df['"y"'] = le.fit_transform(res_df['"y"'])
    return res_df
```

while executing the function the function, i am getting a key error

```
encoded_df = preprocessor(df1)

x = encoded_df.drop(['"y"'],axis =1).values
y = encoded_df['"y"'].values
```

while executing the function the function, i am getting a key error, although i have split the column using sep=';'. Can anyone please help

Comment: Can you give an input example as well? So we can test working code